# How to list sequence of promotions within a company?

Tags: resume, promotion

Suppose I was hired as a Junior Manager from 2010 to 2012, then was promoted to Senior Manager from 2012 to 2014. On a resume/CV is it appropriate to list my title as Senior Manager (2010-2014)?

Often on resumes/CVs on LinkedIn I see people who list the highest position they were promoted to along with the entire duration of their employment at the company, even when they were in more junior roles. Is this normal/reasonable practice?

Comment: no it's not you where only a senior manger for 2 years not 4

Answer (score 10):

I do my CV like this as it shows to the recruiter / employer that i have worked at a company a preset period of time and during that period i was promoted several times.  If you only list the final job title then it looks odd when there is a gap in your employment (Pre 2008 in below eg) period or if listed as 'Senior Developer 2000 - 2010' it looks like you held that role for 10 years when you really held it for 2 years.

Employer: ABC Software Co (2000 - 2010)

- Senior Developer (2008 - 2010)

  - Large description of role
- Developer (2004 - 2008)

  - 1 line description of role (Unless job is still very relevant)
- Junior Developer (2000 - 2004)

  - 1 line description of role or omit description if no longer relevant

Comment: That is what I wanted to say, may be I was not able to explain it. Use Current position as title and list other positions in work experience section.

Comment: On my CV i list all of this under the 'Employment History' section.  To me 'Work experience' makes it seem like it was associated with a short temporary period of unpaid work for school, college, uni.

Answer (score -3):

> On a resume/CV is it appropriate to list my title as Senior Manager
>   (2010-2014)?

**Yes,** But specify year as 2012-2014. Or

I would list as "Currently working as Senior Manager".

You can use your current profile as a Heading of Resume, LinkedIn profile and on your business cards (with or without duration).

However you should list other positions with correct duration in "Work Experience" section of resume.

Comment: This answer is inconsistent. The OP's question was whether it is acceptable to just list your final position.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. It is lying onyour resume and eventually you will caught by someone who verifies the information. The one thing you cannot ever afford to do is lose yoru professional reputation from lying.

Comment: @HLGEM Where I said to lie.. What is wrong with the answer ? I said to be specific and list everything on your resume ?